# Laravel : Models relations vs ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project that uses the ORM heavily instead of model relationships in the controller to get to the data (for eg: using leftJoins instead of establishing proper model relationships using hasMany etc and then retrieving through that)

My question is actually to do with the performance. Is using model relationships to access data faster than using leftJoins? I am not sure if Laravel actually does perform a leftJoin under the hood.

I am on a tight schedule so I want to decide if its actually worth trying to refactor the code to use the model relationships and if it would provide gains in performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's really hard for us to answer such a question for you, especially if you are pressed for time. Laravel (at least) sometimes doesn't use joins. However, I would advise you to build 1 simple test case and run it in your setup.

Comment: As shoieb0101's answer indicates - Laravel's relationships don't perform join, they perform an additional query to get the related (child) components. Sometimes relationships make sense and sometimes joins make sense. Relationships are nice because you have the connected data in a nice foreachable array, where joins only add some data from another table to the results of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel anbd Eloquent may execure queries differently using the relationship as opposed to the join. You can use the barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to see query execution.

My observation is that Laravel will tend to use two queries instead of a join if possible.  It will execute the first query and then using the IDs returned from that query execute a second query on the "joined" table as a "where myID in (1,2,3,4,5..)" and then stitch the results together.

As others have suggested, building up a quick test and seeing what works best in your environment would be the best bet.  I prefer to use the relationships as much as possible becuase you can easily read what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank guys for you wonderful insights!

I changed some of the models to the relationship and loaded it into my Datagrid package to display the content. Based on my tests it seems that Laravel seems to not use joins. It gets the parents ID's and then performs a IN query to retrieve the related model data

It does seems to have a performance gain (cannot confirm just yet) , also means that the code is more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

Joins and relationship are not opposite of each other. Relationships are for ease of development, cleaner, more readable code, easy to maintain. Performance difference is almost non existant unless you are developing a data miner of some sort.

**Edited**
If you are focusing on performance, you can work on implementing caching in a efficient way.